# System requirement for Dedicated TOR system

Tags: configuration

What is the system requirements, including OS, for a system dedicated only to TOR.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As for my experience, a minimal requirements are:

- fast single-core or recent dual-core CPU 500MHz+
- 512Mb of RAM
- 100MBit/s ethernet card
- 4Gb storage
- Linux kernel v4 or recent FreeBSD minimal distro

As a sample you can use yourself - it's a Raspberry Pi 2 - cheap and decent one. From ARM single-board computers, however, I do recommend to use OrangePi or BananaPi - nearly-same price, a way better hardware( like Allwinner H3 quad-core CPU and 1Gb+ RAM).

If you describe your task more specifically - I'll be able to advise you better and help you to set it up

UPDATE:

So as for the task you have described, the proposed solution is:

- A single-board computer, I do recommend [OrangePi Prime](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Orange-Pi-Prime-Development-Board-H5-Quad-core-Support-linux-and-android-Beyond-Raspberry-Pi-2/1553371_32803048527.html) with a power usb cord(included in link above). I'm using the predecessor of it's predecessor - Orange Pi PC, still working, very good and fast. Well, you can pick Raspberry Pi 2 or 3 - but it will cost you the same and be a way slower in a "horsepower".
- A heatsink for single-board computer. If you choose any of the SBC's - all of them do have CPU, and like any CPU it needs cooling. I was starting using cooling from [Deepcool NBridge2](http://www.deepcool.com/product/dcoolingaccessory/accessory/2013-12/48_650.shtml) chipset coolers, then found this [chipset cooler](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2-Sets-Aluminium-Heatsink-Cooler-W-Fan-40x20mm-For-PC-Northbridge-Chipset-Cooling-Wholesale/32484780188.html). You can pick any of them - they're absolutely equal, both tested. To properly fit it on the SBC CPU and it's surrounding chips - just use an iron file to cut off the extra parts of "iron pad" of the cooler. Place it to cover the CPU and to mae no shorts - thermal grease of a good quality is included in both cases. **A word of warning**: *do* **not** *buy cheap/tiny passive coolers for SBC's - you'll make it short-living and slowing itself down because of overheating! This chipset cooler costs 3-5$ above them, but it's worth the price, the difference is huge*
- A USB 5-to-12V step-up adapter - to fire-up the cooler, you'll neet 12 Volts, USB has only 5V, so - there's a lot of power converters e.t.c., I'm using [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2pcs-DC-DC-USB-Step-Up-Power-Supply-Boost-Converter-5V-to-12V-5W/32691220622.html) - works for 1.5+ years, no problems at all, powers up 2 NBridge 2 coolers all this time 24/7. If you do not plan to have any additional SBC's, then you can just solder a cooler's wires to this adapter and be fine. If you do plan or "maybe" to expand the number of the coolers powered - take [this splitter pack](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-pcs-3-Pin-to-2-x-2-pin-3-pin-300mm-Cooling-fan-Y-Splitter/1887359918.html) and make a jack with pins to be connected to the power adapter - and just plug the cooler(or coolers if multiple) to the adapter.
- A patch cord - it's up to your taste! use a decent Cat 5e one - and be just fine about that! you put it to the place where your router stands, so it will work 24/7 eating 5-7Watts per hour and always ready for your requests. just plug it into your router - and you're done!
- A 2-port USB power - or 1 Port - use **ANY** normal usb phone charger capable of giving 2-3 amps. If one port charger is used for case with one sbc - then just plug 5-to-12v into the board's USB port and power up the USB power cord(included with SBC I've linked, for Raspberry Pi see the cables). Apple charger from iPhone 4s was just fine, for example. If you'll have multiple boards - take a look at multi-homed USB chargers: you need just a regular one with at least 2-3 amps *per outlet*. For big quantities of boards I do recommend this [Multi-port docking charger](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/ORICO-10-Ports-Multi-120W-5V2-4A-10-USB-Charger-Station-Dock-with-Holder-for-Phone/105327_32758526424.html), for small amount(1-3) of SBCs take a look at [smaller multi-port chargers](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/QC3-0-charger-usb-charging-head-multi-port-usb-charger-travel-charger/32820338448.html).

After the hardware part is done - just install minimal Debian on it, and tor node as well - and that's it! If you need further help - just drop me a line!

Comment: My plan is to use the system as a dedicated TOR system. I wanted to do some financial research on the darknet.  No sinister plans whatsoever.  I currently have a windows 10 system that I use for "normal" stuff.  I am a nubbie and am reading several books on TOR. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @JHBaily so it will be just a tor node/router, not a GUI desktop? You're about to use your desktop for all the stuff except having TOR node on a separate entity and use it as a gateway to reach Darknet, right?

Comment: Correct.  I want to use a separate device for darknet research.  Is that wise?

Comment: yes it is! do you plan to surf just websites in darknet, i.e. no high-speed things like torrents?

Comment: That is correct. Plan is to research financial information on "listed" companies to attempt to determine if stock are fairly priced and if there is pending news (good or bad) on the company.  On the internet speculative information is scarce because of the reluctance of people to legally expose themselves, hoping that the dark net will have folks willing to discuss their thoughts.

Comment: @JHBaily updated my answer with full hardware list for your task - will be just fine!

Comment: i purchased and installed o/s on raspberry PI 3.  I can not load tor on it.  I followed directions provided in Tor Project (only 32 bit version seems to work), tried other directions found on internet.  Can you help. Please remember that I am a newbie. Thanks

Comment: What OS do you have - raspbian? If so, you better build it from source - on Raspberry Pi 3 tor works fine if built from sources - I've just launched on one of the sites RPi3 with Raspbian and source-compiled Tor, so it works

Comment: I can not get the config file right: virtualaddrnetwork 10.192.0.0.10; 
    translistenaddress 192.168.42.1;   dnslistenaddress 192.168.42.1.   can you suggest values?  thank

Comment: well, for a virtualaddrnetwork you should use *a network*, with CIDR mask after a slash, not the IP address - like this: `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1` . and listenaddress'es are just **static** IPs of the interfaces of your Tor box: you can have as many as you wish. Now - as Tor evolves - the directives like `XXXListenAddress ip` are supposed to be deprecated in favour of the universal `XXXPort ip:port`

Comment: I have found a multitude of posting regarding TOR and xfinity (I use xfinity).  Could this be the problem I am having.  Installing TOR should be fairly standard but I am having a devil of the time with the transport and DNS listening address. I have bought a dedicated Raspberry IP3 for this project.  The Raspberry works fine and it online using "my normal" network connection, but I can not see the Onion network. Any suggestions?

Comment: how exactly do you try to reach the onion network through your raspberry pi 3 with Tor installed?

Comment: 1. Raspberry on home network because i can surf the web using chromium

Comment: 1. Raspberry on home network because i can surf the web using chromium 2.  I have installed Tor on Raspberry 3. I open a terminal session 4. i enter "sudo service tor start" 5.I get "job for tor service failed. see..." 6.  i enter " sudo service service tor status -s" 7. I get "starting daemon  ... warn could not bind to 10.0.0.16:40  warn could not bind to 10.0.0.16:9000 ; cannot assign requested address.   failed to parse/validate config...

Comment: hmm... contact me on facebook so we'll set it up together tomorrow - looks like some part of configuration is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  I do not have a facebook page or any other online social account, except linkedin.  I will have to find another solution.  Thanks again for the offer.

Comment: You should use Raspberry Pi as a HTTPS+SOCKS proxy in your browser in your case. You set the LAN IP address for your Pi *statically* in `/etc/network/interfaces` - out of the DHCP range in your LAN(if there's any). Binding for a privileged(<1024 or <4096 - depends on system settings) port requre a root privileges, so put the line `User xxx` in your torrc config **the very last one**. Attach your torrc config and the output of `ip a` or `ifconfig` commands to your question - so I'll take a look and we will fix it.

Comment: i have installed tor successfully.  I have downloaded tor browser.  It appears to be ok. When I try to execute tor start-tor-browser, nothing happens. Any ideas.

Comment: you can use your regular firefox - just type in a SOCKS proxy from your Pi. Tor Browser **do** have problems with an external tor instance, so use Firefox and just go through tor's SOCKS proxy

Comment: Finally got it all going. Some things are not intuitive, but I got it done.  I can not tell you how much I appreciate your help. I can not pay you but I can pay it forward.  Take care. God Bless